# Автодополнение Emmet в WebStorm

Tags: html, webstorm, autocomplete, emmet

В WebStorm автоматически всплывают подсказки с классами при заполнении поля `class` в тегах.
Выглядит это вот так:

[image: Автодополнение внутри тега]

Но для сокращений Emmet такие подсказки не показываются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогичная проблема возникла у автора [следующего вопроса на Хабр Q&A](https://qna.habr.com/q/544835), но ответа он так и не получил.
Возможно ли использовать автодополнение с плагином Emmet? Если да, то как?
Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, автодополнение для Emmet не поддерживается, проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-397](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-397)

Comment: Спасибо! Можно ли как то реализовать этот функционал плагинами? Учитывая, что тикет по ссылке был открыт 9 лет назад, не думаю, что в ближайшее время эта фича появится.